# How to use multiple Icomoon fonts (multiple font-family)

Tags: css, font-face

Icomoon fonts work fine if you only have one font-family, but what if I have another font-family created and want to use together with the first one? I tried to do something like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'icomoon';
  src:url('icomoon.eot');
  src:url('icomoon.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('icomoon.woff') format('woff'),
  url('icomoon.ttf') format('truetype'),
  url('icomoon.svg#icomoon') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'abccons';
  src:url('fonts/abccons.eot');
  src:url('fonts/abccons.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('fonts/abccons.woff') format('woff'),
  url('fonts/abccons.ttf') format('truetype'),
  url('fonts/abccons.svg#abccons') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

I have the font file names exactly same to the font-family. Also I am using "data-icon" attribute for the first font icon, and using "data-icon2" fot the second.

```
[data-icon]:before { content:attr(data-icon); font-family:'icomoon'; font-variant:normal; font-weight:normal; line-height:1; speak:none; text-transform:none; -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased; }

[data-icon2]:before { content:attr(data-icon2); font-family:'abccons'; font-variant:normal; font-weight:normal; line-height:1; speak:none; text-transform:none; -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased; }
```

Not sure if I am doing it in a right way. The fonts are loaded in the way described in http://css-tricks.com/html-for-icon-font-usage/ . The result is: the first font loads correctly, while the second seems already loaded something, but all shown as a square shape, not the fonts. If I set as data-icon2 in css file but use data-icon3 in html (intend to make errors), then nothing loads.

Any idea?

Answer (score -2):

Check the path.....There is a beautiful tutorial on how to use Icomoon icons
http://chipcullen.com/how-to-use-icomoon-and-icon-fonts-part-1-basic-usage/ .It will help you

Comment: This doesn't help use both font-families